# Restore-WDPackage under another website name

Tags: powershell, iis, visual-studio-2013, deployment, restore

I am using this script to deploy web packages that have been generated by VS2013

```
function SyncPackage([Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][ValidateSet('DEV','TST','PRD', ignorecase=$False)][string]$env)
{

$redisHost=""
$redisAccessKey=""
$parameters = @{"Environment"=$env}
set-location "FILESYSTEM::d:\packages"
$srcServer = ("Web" + $env + "02.server")
$desterver = ("Web" + $env + "01.server")
New-WDPublishSettings -ComputerName $srcServer -AgentType MSDepSvc -FileName server01.publishsettings
New-WDPublishSettings -ComputerName $desterver -AgentType MSDepSvc -FileName server02.publishsettings

Restore-WDPackage .\(app)\server.Web.(App).DeviceService.zip -DestinationPublishSettings server01.publishsettings -Parameters $parameters

Read-host "Press <Enter> To Sync or Ctrl+C to cancel:>"
Sync-WDServer -SourcePublishSettings server01.publishsettings -DestinationPublishSettings server02.publishsettings
}
cls
SyncPackage -env TST
```

My issue is that the (app) is under another name on the IIS server. Is there anyway to run the restore under another website name?

EDIT: As a work around I can use the publish function on VS2013 and use the website name from IIS in the Connection > Site name field of the publish wizard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could you try to add the key "IIS Web Application Name" to your parameters?

```
$site = "myapp.name"
Restore-WDPackage $package -DestinationPublishSettings $publishSettingsFile -Parameters @{ "IIS Web Application Name"="$site" }
```